# Crashlytics beta distribution in Xcode / IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics

Trying to figure out how to do beta test distribution via Crashlytics. Their cryptic instructions state that all you have to do is "build for archive" but that command doesn't exist anymore. I've created an archive (Product => Archive) and exported ad hoc release, but Crashlytics doesn't pick it up.

How do I upload a release?

Answer (score 49):

If the app doesn't pick up your new archive, the way to manually distribute it is a little hidden. On the Beta tab in the app, first click "ACTIVE", then click "ARCHIVES":

[image]

Comment: That's totally different from the Crashlytics app that I've got. I'm having problems with it not detecting archive builds on a project and I don't have any of the UI you have shown.

Comment: Wow thanks, I had never guessed that! Solved my problem.

Comment: Wow, saved me. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

Quit the Mac app, then run this command to clear the local cache:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac`

Comment: Thanks. In my case the problem is I had a previous version installed with different credentials. Seems like your fix is the one for that case.

Answer (score 2):

I never got the local app to work, but did succeed using this command line approach: `/path/to/Crashlytics.framework/submit <API_KEY> <BUILD_SECRET> -ipaPath /path/to/my.ipa -emails TestEmail@crashlytics.com,AmazingTester@twitter.com -notesPath ~/Notes/ReleaseNotes.txt -groupAliases ﻿GroupAlias,GroupAlias2﻿`

Taken from: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/370383-how-do-i-use-ios-build-servers-with-beta

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem whenever I delete an archive in xcode... the next archive action fails to trigger the distribution option and it hangs next time I do try to distribute...

I fix it by restarting xcode, cleaning the project, running the crashlytics installation (cmd+b, cmd+r when prompted, no new tokens necessary), then clicking archive again.

Works every time. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. I tried to upload build to Fabric manually building .xcarchive manually on build server (it was some problems with automatically build, so it was executed manually). Then I copied .xcarchive to my local machine with installed Fabric plugin. But it was not apeared in ARCHIVE section.

To solve this problem you should double-click .xcarchive to add it to Xcode Orginizer (Xcode > Window > Organizer).